# @Value with final field

Tags: spring, yaml

```
    @Value("${a.b.cache.expireInMinutes:15}")
    private final long expireInMinutes;
```

Looks like sometimes the final field with annotation `@Value` cannot pick up the value from application.yaml:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'long' available
```

#### Update

If we do method injection, such issue disappears!

Comment: There is no active profile so it should use the default application.yaml

Comment: Final and static Fields cant be injected with Springs @Value. You would have to do Setter Injection, which isn't necessarily the cleanest way to design this

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can inject values into a final field is through Constructor Injection, If it is sometimes working in your case it is because of Spring doing some nasty stuff. I suggest removing the final from the variable.

Comment: Yep i find If I use method injection, it works